# Kohana-3.3 routing

Tags: routes, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

I have problem with routing. My route looks like this:

`Route::set('restapi', 'restapi/<version>(/<directory>)/<controller>(.<format>)',
    array(
        'version' => 'v1',
        'format'  => '(json|xml|csv|html)',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'format' => 'json',
    ));`

And my question is: how my url should looks like? 
Path for Api: Controller/restapi/api.php 
Thanks for help.

Comment: /restapi/v1/Directory/USER.json Or /restapi/v1/User.json where user is your controller name.

Comment: I already solved this. It was problem with htaccess configuration.

Comment: It's very strange if you solved your problem through .htaccess. Default Kohana .htaccess shouldn't be changed. Factually routers are necessary for getting beautiful links without changing .htaccess.